# Cast double to char in Matlab? Why strcat('hello', char(324)) not working?

Tags: matlab, casting, char, double, ascii

**Goal**

> >> strcat('D_', char(2340), '.txt')
>
> D_2340.txt

but failure with D_.txt. Why does it ignore the double casted to char? I also tried cast(340, 'char') but the same ignorance problem. It worked with `strcat('hello','324','.txt')` but not with the latter. Why this behaviour?

Comment: I think you should be using `num2str` instead of trying to cast to `char`. I don't have Matlab to test this right now but I would imagine that `char(65) == 'A'` where as `num2str(65)` definitely equals `'65'`

Comment: @Dan thank you +1, it solved the question. Please, move it to an answer, worth it? Well this could have some explanation, why is the casting not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `num2str` instead of trying to cast to char. I don't have Matlab to test this right now but I would imagine that `char(65) == 'A'` (i.e. ascii) where as `num2str(65)` definitely equals `'65'` so who knows what character char(2340) will return...

Comment: +1 Perfect! Now I understood it. The casting works but it tries to cast 2340 to its ASCII counterpart that is undefined. It explains why the casting from the double to string returned empty. Thank you.

Comment: @hhh: actually `char(2340)` is some Unicode character outside the range of Latin alphabet. It gives me: `D_त.txt`